# Why can't I loop through CSV rows twice in the same with block?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Say there is a CSV file with two columns, if I want to loop through reader object for the second time in the same with block, it will return Null. 
For instance, in the following codes, both of list m, n is empty. 
Is there any explanation for this? Thank you.

```
import csv

with open('exercise.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    x, y, z = [], [], []
    for row in reader:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[0])
        z.append(row[1])
    print(len(x), len(y), len(z))

    m, n = [], []
    for row in reader:
        m.append(row[0])
    for row in reader:
        n.append(row[1])
    print(len(m), len(n))
```

Comment: It happens because reader becomes exhausted when you iterate thru it one time. Take a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html - it utilizes the `__next__` method. If you want it to work assign `reader` again or add `m` and `n` to the first loop.

Comment: or use `f.seek(0)` to rewind the file.

Comment: If you have to work with CSV files, I suggest to use pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Just make it in one loop.

```
import csv

with open('exercise.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    x, y, z, m, n = [], [], [], [], []
    for row in reader:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[0])
        z.append(row[1])
    print(len(x), len(y), len(z))
        m.append(row[0])
        n.append(row[1])
    print(len(m), len(n))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).